# Can't index a list in Scala because of "java.util.List[etc... does not take parameters error"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list I'm collecting using this syntax.

```
  val cutoff = df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank() over bydf).filter("rank=5").select("amount").collectAsList()

[[10.5]]
```

and when I try to index the list cutoff to extract the value 10.5, I get this error:

```
Error:(38, 17) java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] does not take parameters
```

How can I fix this and extract 10.5 from this nested list

Comment: collect is enough, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are collecting on a Dataframe you get back a List of Row. The easiest thing to do would be to turn it into a Dataset before collecting. That is (presuming amount is a Double):

```
val cutoff = df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank() over bydf).filter("rank=5").select("amount").as[Double].collectAsList()
```